# Electron - corrupted file when convert docx file to pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, electron, docx

I have this code in my background.js file of my electron app.

```js
ipcMain.on('runProcess', async (event, ...args) => {
    const docData = JSON.parse(args[0]);
    const docPaths = [];
    const handler = new TemplateHandler({
        delimiters: {
            tagStart: '{{',
            tagEnd: '}}'
        }
    });
    for( let i = 0; i < docData.length; i++ ) {
        const fileName = `comunication-${docData[i].ragioneSociale}.docx`
        handler.process(docTemplate, docData[i])
            .then( (result) => {
                dialog.showSaveDialog({
                    title: 'Multimailer',
                    buttonLabel: 'Salva file',
                    defaultPath: fileName,
                    filters: [
                        {
                            name: 'MS Word file',
                            extensions: ['docx']
                        }
                    ],
                    properties: [
                        'dontAddToRecent',
                        'showHiddenFiles',
                        'showOverwriteConfirmation'
                    ]
                }).then( (filePath) => {
                    if( filePath.canceled ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    docPaths.push(filePath.filePath);
                    fs.writeFile(filePath.filePath, result, (err) => {
                        if( err ) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        for( let p = 0; p < docPaths.length; p++ ) {
                            formData.set('__EVENTTARGET', '');
                            formData.set('__EVENTARGUMENT', '');
                            formData.set('__VIEWSTATE', '');
                            formData.set('ctl00$MainContent$fu', fs.readFileSync(docPaths[p]), {
                                filename: fileName,
                                contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
                            });
                            formData.set('ctl00$MainContent$btnConvert', 'Convert');
                            formData.set('ctl00$MainContent$fuZip', '');
                            //
                            fetch('http://mirror1.convertonlinefree.com',{
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36'
                                },
                                body: formData
                            }).then( async (response) => {
                                const outputFile = await response.arrayBuffer();
                                console.log(outputFile);
                                fs.writeFile( docPaths[p].replace('.docx', '.pdf'), Buffer.from(outputFile), 'utf-8', (err) => {
                                    if( err ) {
                                        throw err;
                                    }
                                    fs.unlink( docPaths[p], (err) => {
                                        if( err ) {
                                            throw err
                                        }
                                        console.log('File docx rimosso correttamente');
                                    });
                                    //
                                });
                            }).catch( (e) => {
                                throw e;
                            });
                            
                        }
                    });
                }).catch( (e) => {
                    throw e;
                });
            }).catch( (e) => {
                throw e;
            });
    }
})
```

I need to convert a docx to a pdf and I'm using an online api service that I've found by searching between github repository. The service will give me back the converted file, and I need to save it, but I'm facing the issue that the saved pdf is corrupt. Is there something wrong into the code?Is there any good library I can use to get my file converted from docx to pdf?

Comment: I'm just replacing the final name of the file after I get it from the web service. I don't need to save an xls buta pdf and the path where I save the file initially will create a docx

Comment: The response is a buffer, but at the moment I'm looking for a better converter, like a python script or another nodejs lib

Comment: @KJ `fs.writeFile` will not work with the result if passed directly, array buffer is not supported. I can just try to pass the response to the writeFile function, but I think will fail ?